Why do pages I edit using Elementor become messy from time to time?
Normally it should look like this
This is what happens when it gets messed up
I can restore specific pages by updating the page using elementorUpdate using elementor, or I can restore all pages by switching themes. But they are all temporary recoveries, and the problem will reappear after a while, and the pages with problems are all random.
How should I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Could be bad cache. From the looks its not loading your style or its overwritten by another style after cache .. use inspector the see if your style is loaded and if when its loaded.

@Snuffy Thank you for your comment Snuffy, I have solve this problem, the problem was with the WP Rocket cache optimization plugins. I removed the REMOVE UNUSED CSS option and the problem was solved.
